# Unable to add a Application Server to the existing SharePoint Farm

Tags: 2010, administration

I have a SharePoint application server and DB Server which is running well .
Now as a part of Requirement we want to install Sharepoint on to the DB Server as well.
After Installing and connecting it to farm and we found the server added to list in "Manager servers in farm " but with a status message **"Upgrade Required"** .

We ran the configuration wizard but came up with the error below

> "An exception of the type System.IO.FileNotFoundException was thrown.
>   Additional exception information : Could not find file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config' "

Please help in Solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the answer is logically correct but it quite worked for me . 
I had re installed office web apps in the server and then ran the configuration wizard.
The wizard ran successfully .

May be this step might be useful for someone else but did not quite get the logic .